# Conference proposal voting application

Tags: open-source, self-hosted, voting

I'm looking for an open source conference proposal voting application that can be self-hosted.

I'd love to have something [like the SXSW PanelPicker](http://panelpicker.sxsw.com/vote), and have searched high and low and can't find anything like it.

The use case is for a several day long non-profit conference where we would like potential participants choose the session presented by way of popular vote.

Comment: does anything in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39301/web-tool-that-allows-users-to-submit-ideas-and-vote-on-other-users-ideas?rq=1 look helpful to you?