# Web tool that allows users to submit ideas and vote on other users ideas

Tags: web-apps, survey, voting

Just as the title states, I am looking for a web-based tool that would allow users to submit an idea to be voted upon. Additionally, all other users should be able to see all current ideas and I should be able to vote on certain ones. It would also be nice if I could see once a particular idea had a certain number of votes.

Comment: This got me wondering - has *IdeaTorrent* disappeared? It's what was provided by SourceForge some years ago, when they were still offering hosted apps. It allowed users to add questions/issues (the problems that needed to be solved), and for every such issue, any number of solutions could be posted, which could then be voted on.

Answer (score 1):

[UserVoice](https://www.uservoice.com/) is the popular one for this, but it is expensive.

There are not a lot free options, one that seems to be very good is [www.idea.informer.com](http://www.idea.informer.com)

Answer (score 1):

I am one of the developers of PollUnit. With https://pollunit.com you can create votings where users can add ideas.

You can choose between various voting types like boolean votes, star rating, [dot voting](https://pollunit.com/en/tutorials/dot_voting) and you can also find [consensus based decisions](https://pollunit.com/en/tutorials/consensus). We have also gratis accounts for small teams.

Here is an example how a dot voting could look like:

[image]

UPDATE

We released a idea collection/feedback/brainstorming feature. I think this is exactly what you are looking for. See screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Along with UserVoice which is very well known, here are 3 alternatives:

- [canny](https://canny.io/) - A hosted tool with a few integrations with slack, Jira etc.. and starts at $40 a month
- [fider](http://getfider.com/) - Offers both hosted and self hosted options
- [receptive](https://www.receptive.io/) - More expensive, but more features and various integrations.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FosWiki](https://foswiki.org/Home/WebHome), a simple Wiki System and employ the one of the [Vote Plugins](https://foswiki.org/Extensions/TopicVotePlugin) to capture and display votes.

We use this at my company to share and vote on new ideas.